# Maintain width and height of rotated square divs in CSS grid (responsive solution)

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I am trying to maintain a consistent height and width of my square divs using CSS grid across devices. I've rotated the grid in an attempt to make a *'diamond'* shape, but this shape changes when the screen resizes. How do I keep a consistent perfect rotated square width and height in my grid where the container takes up the entire viewport height and width?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid>div {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are rotating the element `45deg`, the width/height need to follow this formula: `height = width = 50vh / cos(45deg) = 50vh / 0.707`. You need to also adjust the `transform-origin` and add a small translation to correct the position:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  transform: translateY(-29%) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin:bottom left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:calc(50vh/0.707);
  height:calc(50vh/0.707);
}

.grid>div {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
    <div>
      box
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

The `translateY(-29%)` is to move the bottom left origin to the center of the left edge before the rotation:

[image]

The blue distance is equal to `50vh - (100vh - Width) = 50vh - 100vh + 50vh/0.707 = 50vh*(1 + 1.414) - 50vh*2 = 0.414*50vh`

and if we divide this result with the width (`0.414/1.414`) we have our `29%`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed response, this worked.