# How to make parent div follow the height of a 45 degree rotated child div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find a way that I can make the parent div take the height of the rotated child div.

The issue seems to be with the child div being rotated but the parent div is aware of the non-rotate height of the child div.

I need the red box to cover the whole of the green diamond. Any recommendation guys?

Thank you in advance guys.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KOWXRB

```
.parent-container {
   position: relative;
   background: red;
}

.child-diamond {
   position: relative;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   background: #1eff00;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="child-diamond"></div>
</div>
```

Update 2: Thanks to Rotem Lurx Horovitz for the suggestion. I added additional js to re-calculate the div should user resize their browser.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    fixDiamondContainerHeight();
});

$(function () {
    fixDiamondContainerHeight();
});

function fixDiamondContainerHeight() {
    //Calculate the height of the parent div for diamond shape
let $a = $('.child-diamond').width(),
$b = $('.child-diamond').height(),
$c = Math.sqrt((Math.pow($a, 2)) + (Math.pow($b, 2)));

$('.parent-container').height($c);
}
```

Comment: transform is only a visual effect (like position:relative;) , the element remains in its original place with its original size, you will need to reset transform-origin and margin around it to clear the area where it stands.https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mNWqWX

Comment: related in case you want a CSS only solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875824/8620333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For maximum flexibility (no matter what size the green square has) - use javascript to calculate the new height by looking at this like a right triangle, and using the [Pythagoras Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):

if the formula is:
**a²+b²=c²**

then:
**c = √(a²+b²)**

then just set the `parent-container` height with the value of c.

```
let $a = $('.child-diamond').width(),
$b = $('.child-diamond').height(),
$c = Math.sqrt((Math.pow($a, 2)) + (Math.pow($b, 2)));

$('.parent-container').height($c);
```

(example uses jQuery)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgBaVR

Comment: Thank you @Rotem Lurx Horovitz! Was hoping not to use any js but I can see that will be impossible. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi @Rotem Lurx Horovitz, how can I get the parent div to recalculate when user changes their browser size?

Answer (score 0):

To cover whole green box inside red box.

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
 let height = $('.child-diamond').height();
 let width = $('.child-diamond').width();
 let diagonal = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(height, 2)) + (Math.pow(width, 2)));
 let leftPadding = (diagonal - width)/2;
 $('.parent-container').css({'height': diagonal, 'padding-left': leftPadding + 'px'});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This can also be done simply by CSS.

Add this to your parent div `display:table;`

```
.parent-container {
   position: relative;
   background: red;
   display:table
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgBYaV

Comment: your forgot to mention to add extra margin  about transform behavior ...javscript will help do the math here ;)